# Database Design - Removing ambiguity without adding loop

Tags: database-design

I'm looking for a better approach to the problem (and my solution) described below. I've attached an image of my initial design

[image]

Let's say I have a cat, and I'd like to find its owners and what vets they took it to. I can easily find out what vets the cat has been to, if I choose a specific vet, I want to know what owners have brought the cat there. I run into problems here, because the list of owners that came to the vet may include owners who own cats other than the one I've found. So now my thought is to say I've got this cat, and I'm at this vet, I want to see all owners who have taken this cat to this vet.

[image]

So I add a relationship between the cat and it's owners (this cat is owned by many people, and each of them has multiple cats i.e. many-many). Now I can say that I know these people own this cat, and I know what vets the cat has been to. I can now select all owners who have taken the cat to a specific vet.

I am of course aware that loops are not inherently bad in a database design (as long as no redundancy exists). I'm not convinced that redundancy doesn't exist here, the many-to-many relationship makes me feel that this is the only approach, but I was hoping that someone might have a better approach to this problem.

Comment: Can someone visit the doctor with a cat they don't own?

Comment: Lets say no. I see what you are getting at, it shows information I can get that I didn't originally expect. My main goal is if I have a cat, I can get a vet it was at, and once I have the vet, I can find the owner of the cat, and that is it.

Comment: Good question. **(1)** By “vet” you mean the veterinarian’s office, right? I assume that a specific `Cat` can be taken to the same `Vet` by different `Owners`  **in distinct points in time**. So, **(2)** is it possible for a particular `Cat` to be brought to the same specific `Vet` by multiple (i.e., **one-to-many**) `Owners` **concurrently**, that is, at the same time? **(3)** Could you expand on the loop issue?

Comment: Yes, I did mean veterinarian's office, and a cat can be brought to a vet by multiple owners concurrently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your scenario properly, the following assertions are relevant:

- A `Cat` has **one-to-many** `Owners` or, put another way, an `Owner` has **one-to-many** `Cats`.
- A `Cat` is involved in **one-to-many** `Visits` to **one-to-many** `Vets`.
- In **each** `Visit` to **one** specific `Vet`, **one**  `Cat` is taken by **one-to-many** `Owners`.

From this set of assertions I have derived (and uploaded to Dropbox) the following [**Cats and Vets Data Model**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/czlgzsb6sj6g3h5/Cats%20and%20Vets%20Data%20Model.pdf), which depicts the way I would approach your specifications.

As you can see in such IDEF1X<sup>[1]</sup> data model, I consider important to add an entity that represents the specific **event** when a `Cat` (brought by **one-to-many** `CatOwners`) visited a particular `Vet`, and I called it `Visit`.

And yes, I also think that the `CatOwner` entity (that you have alredy included in your diagram) is very useful since, in addition to preventing a `Person` who is not an `Owner` of a particular `Cat` from taking such `Cat` to a `Vet`, it may also serve the purpose of relating a `Cat` and **one-to-many** of its `Owners` to a specific `Visit` to an individual `Vet`.

It is also necessary to add a **many-to-many** relationship to provide the advantage of associating **one-to-many** `CatOwner` ocurrences to **one-to-many** `Visit` instances (each `Visit` received by **one** particular `Vet`), and I propose the relationship called `CatOwnerVisit` to cover this requirement.

### Note

<sub>1. **[IDEF1X](http://www.idef.com/idef1x.htm)** is a **highly recommendable** data modeling technique that was defined as a **standard** in december 1993 by the U.S. National Institute of Standards and Technology (**NIST**).</sub>